# How to store multiple file names only (not these files's contents) in to another text file

Tags: shell

Let say I have three configuration files in Linux terminal. All three file contains some data in its. I need to create another file by name let say "list". I want to copy only text name of these files i.e "ram" or "rom" or "eprom"  in to "list" file but not the contents of these three files. What should I do in shell so that ram, rom and eprom names copied in to "list" file?

1) ram.cfg 2) rom.cfg 3) eprom.cfg

The contents of the "list" file should only be "ram", "rom" and "eprom" each name in individual line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve depends on where the files are, but I answer you for the case they are all in the same directory.

Linux does not know file extensions.

You can do something like `ls > list` or `ls | grep .cfg > list`

and then use vim with `:%s/\..*/` or `:%s/\.cfg/`  to delete all file extensions.

You might want to replace the first regex with something more specific though since when a file has more than one dot it will delete anything after the first appearance of dot.

You can combine this to one step though:

```
 ls | grep .cfg | sed -e 's/\.cfg$//' > list
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the meaning of putting $ here?

Comment: $ end of line; just to make sure if you have a file named foo.bar.cfg (which could happen for e.g. www.cfg.myserver.com.cfg), that only the .cfg at the end of line is removed.
Which makes me notice you might need to adjust the grep command since www.cfg.myserver.com would also be listed ;) If, and only if that might be the case for you which might be unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Other methods:

```
[ -e list ] && : > list

for f in *.cfg; do echo ${f%%.*} >> list; done; cat list


[ -e list ] && : > list

ls *.cfg | xargs -r -Ifile bash -c 'f=file;echo ${f%%.*}>>list'; cat list;
```